# Why maphilight option 'alwayson' not working properly?

Tags: maphilight

I am facing problem with `jquery` plugin `maphilight`. My code is as follows-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery maphilight documentation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            var num = 0;

            addElement = function addElement(str) {

                var ni = document.getElementById('MDI');

                ni.innerHTML = "";
                var newitem = document.createElement('img');
                var newmap = document.createElement('map');
                var newarea = document.createElement('area');
                var imgIdName = 'myimg' + num;

                newarea.href = 'https://www.mapsofworld.com/usa/usa-state-and-capital-map.html';
                newarea.shape = 'circle';
                newarea.coords = "172,233,11"

                newmap.appendChild(newarea);
                newmap.setAttribute('name', 'mymap' + num, 0);

                newitem.src = 'Images/' + str + '.PNG';
                newitem.useMap = '#' + 'mymap' + num;

                newitem.id = imgIdName;
                newitem.className = 'clMapState' + num;
                ni.appendChild(newitem);
                ni.appendChild(newmap);

                $('.clMapState' + num).maphilight();
                $('.clMapState' + num).data('maphilight', { 'alwaysOn': true, fillColor: 'DC143C' });

                num++;

                return false;
            }

            $('.map').maphilight();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="table">

        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <img src="Images/US_map.PNG" class="map" usemap="#simple" id="usMapId2">
                    <map name="simple">
                        <area data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"0000ff","fillOpacity":0.6}' onclick="addElement('ID')" shape="poly" coords="171,180,263,197,273,143,245,143,234,116,225,112,231,95,219,76,215,68,213,57,218,38,204,35,192,97,196,105,179,127,183,136" alt="ID" title="ID"><!-- data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"0000ff","fillOpacity":0.6}'  href="https://grasptheblock.wixsite.com/patchwork-eden"-->
                        <area data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"0000ff","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"0000ff","fillOpacity":0.6}' onclick="addElement('MT')" shape="poly" coords="218,37,213,52,216,63,220,73,230,92,225,111,233,111,236,128,242,143,264,140,274,133,383,148,390,62" alt="MT" title="MT">
                    </map>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="MDI">

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code I am trying to creating an image map dynamically and highlighting the map area with `maphilight` plugin. It is working perfectly for first two/three times. But after that, the `maphilight` option `alwaysOn` true is not working properly.